# What is this? maybe a sensor?

Tags: electrical, ford, focus, connector

I discovered this loose tape connector while fixing a coolant hose by the heater matrix.

There are two more of these attached to the very bottom of the windscreen glass on each end, the loose one came from the middle somewhere.

[image: Sensor type thing]

I can't find anywhere for it to plug back into, or any way to reattach it to the windscreen.
If relevant - Car is Focus ST MK2

What is it and what does it do?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That looks like a flex connector that has broken off. Perhaps part of a windscreen heater?

[image]
<sup>Labone Heated Screen Connectors</sup>

Answer (score 16):

It's one of the Heated Windscreen connectors. They have a reputation for breaking off on the Ford Focus, because the wipers hit them if they're not routed correctly.

It's common for replacement glass companies to not notice that the car has a heated screen, so don't spend any money fixing it until you've confirmed that it still has a heated screen.

This picture shows the element in place on the left side of the engine bay.

[image: Ford Heated Screen element]

Comment: It's as if the designers _wanted_ it to shear off...